# Delete fact from kSession using facthandle

Tags: java, spring, drools, rule-engine, kie

I am trying to insert two types of java objects(facts) in kSession. I am getting properties of these objects from excel file.

Objects(facts) are lets say 10 of type 1 and 20 of type 2 i.e. 1 object of type 1(c1) is paired with 2 objects of type 2(p1, p2) via an id present in both objects.

All these objects(facts) are pushed in kSession and rules are fired.

Now i want to update p1 so that next time rules will be fired on updated facts i.e. c1(updatedp1, p2)

Comment: And how's the question related to the title?

Comment: I want to update the fact of type 2 by deleting the previous fact and inserting new fact using factHandler Delete method.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish instead of the way you are trying to solve (update p1, remove p2, etc.). What use case are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

After you've fired the rules, you can delete the previous handle and get a new one by inserting the object (i.e., FactHandle fHandle = kSession.insert(...)) you've just read from the file.